# Associating Visual Studio Code with Git in Mac

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I want to configure my default git editor to Visual Studio Code, but I get the following error after configure it and then use it:

```
username ~ $ git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
username ~ $ git config --global -e
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found  
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
```

I have no idea how to fix it... Do you know how I could do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: the "code" executable is not in the PATH. Perhaps your solution is in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Answer (score 31):

On your VSCode,

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

> Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH

It will set 'code' to executable PATH of vscode.

Now run below in terminal:

> git config --global --edit

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the `code` command is not added in PATH. Follow these steps to add the `code` command in PATH:

1. Press `SHIFT+Command+P`.
2. A input field comes up. Type `code install` and an option

> Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`

comes up. Click on that.

4. The `code` command gets added to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to push from VS code terminal in your project directory...

```
git commit -m 'commitname'
git push
```

that's all enjoy your coding...