# Trying git commit amend, getting a wait error or problem with editor

Tags: git, github, commit, git-config

newb here and I'm learning about git. Currently the lesson requires a git commit --amend and I've gotten the following:

```
Macintoshs-MacBook-Pro:learning-git-hub macintoshhd$ git commit --amend
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Not sure what's going on here, but would love to fix it!

Git commit --amend, was expecting the amend to get committed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58348699/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bvscode%5D+waiting+for+your+editor+to+close+code+command+not+found